# Boost documentation problem

Tags: boost

I'm trying to view the boost documentation at their website: http://www.boost.org/doc/
But it says Forbidden.

Any way I can download the documentation, or get past this error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting a similar error from the front page for the link to the docs. However I vaguely remember that if you download the boost libraries, the tarball/zip contains a copy of the docs.

Comment: Yep, full HTML documentation in the archive (and on the SVN).

Answer (score 0):

We've had some hosting problems related to the Boost documentation. Things should get resolved really soon. In fact at least the docs for the latest 2 releases are already up again (for me), see http://www.boost.org/doc/.